# Real Points of resolution of singularities of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the scheme $X = \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$. Scheme-theoretically, it's a one dimensional scheme with one real, singular point (there are, of course, other complex points). I'm interested in finding the structure of the real points of the resolution of $X$, but I'm having trouble visualizing exactly what I get.

I think I want to do something like the following: embedd $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ and then blow up at the origin and see what I get. Here's the part where I start to get confused. Over the complex numbers, I know if I were to do this, since $(x^2+y^2)=(x+iy)(x-iy)$, I would have my scheme be two lines intersecting transversally, which under the blow up would turn in to two disjoint lines, and the resolution of singularities would be from two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ to two transversally intersecting lines.

When I try and think about doing this same sort of business over $\mathbb{R}$, I get confused about where the lines live. I know I ought to have something that looks like two disjoint lines embedded in $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{R}$, but I don't really understand how much of these lines are real points and how much of them are complex points.

I'd like it if someone could give me some advice on how to approach the problem or perhaps some sort of solution which makes explicit where the real points are in a (the?) resolution of singularities of this scheme.

Comment: Here's a no-calculation argument that I think is even correct. On the complement of the origin in $\mathbf A^2_{\mathbf R}$ the blowup is an $\mathbf R$-isomorphism. Since there were no real points here before blowup, there won't be afterwards. On the exceptional divisor you get two points corresponding to the two tangent directions of your original $X$ at the origin. But those tangent directions are non-real, so you get two non-real points on the exceptional divisor. (If you prefer, complex conjugation swaps the two components of $X$, so it must swap those 2 points, hence they are non-real.)

Comment: Relapsarian: Yes, this is a good argument! I thought of this yesterday after Mohan's answer- it's nice to know someone else thought of it and the argument works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$. If you blow up, the resolution is covered by two open sets of the form $A[x/y],A[y/x]$ and both are isomorphic to a ring of the form $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+1)$ and thus the resolution has no real points.